# How to fix mistakes in decimal column formatted as string

Tags: c#, ssis

I need to ingest data from excel files where a decimal column is populated by users without any format control.
I cannot do anything about it because it's an external source.

A value that should be "2.9" can show up like ".2.9", "2..9", "2.9.", etc.
At the moment I'm working around it playing cat and mouse with nested ifs (below).
Is there a better solution?

```
case int n when n >= 50 && n <= 57: 
    if (value == null)
    {
        return DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        isNumeric = double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out _);
        if (isNumeric == false)
        {
            return Convert.ToDouble(value.ToString().Replace("..", "."));
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about throwing an error and let the user fix it? Silently trying to fix it might cause undesired behavior, as you don't know what the value should be. (e.g. ".2.9" could be 2.9 or 0.29)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have this (taken from your examples):

```
var strings = new[] { ".2.9", "2..9", "2.9." };
```

...you could split the string by `.`, remove the empty entries and then join them together again with `.` as separator before parsing to double:

```
foreach (var str in strings)
{
    var strParts = str.Split('.', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var joinedString = string.Join('.', strParts);
    double dbl = double.Parse(joinedString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    // Do something with the double
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea. ".2.9" could be either 0.29 or 2.9. There's no way of knowing.

Comment: I agree with you!